# Sourcetree isn't populating my dev branch in pull

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

Ever since I had to recreate my dev branch due to some mishaps with Git, Sourcetree doesn't prepopulate the "dev" branch in the pull and push dialogs. Every other branch works fine, but not dev. It's not a big deal, but I have to select dev manually every time. What gives?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Is your local dev branch set to "track" the remote dev branch?  Right-click, the branch, select "Track remote branch" and see if anything is selected.

Comment: @BJMyers It appears that was it! Duh!

Comment: Ok.  I'll post an answer for posterity. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Remote branch to pull" dialog is pre-populated based on the remote branch that is being "tracked" by your local branch.  (When you check out or push to a remote branch, SourceTree usually sets this up automatically.)

If your dev branch is not tracking a remote branch, then the dialog will load with no selection.  To change this, right-click the branch and select 'Track remote branch."

[image: Checking tracking branch for git repository]